# How to recivie the parameter passes from JSP inside the Skelton class of ApacheAxis2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I want to recive the Parameter from the JSP to the Skelton class of ApacheAxis2  .

Please see my program below :

```
package samples.quickstart;

public class StockQuoteServiceSkeleton implements
        StockQuoteServiceSkeletonInterface {

    public samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPriceResponse getPrice(
            samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPrice getPrice0) {

        System.out.println(getPrice0.toString());

        samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPriceResponse response = new samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPriceResponse();

        HashMap map = new HashMap();

        map.put("Kiran", "122");
        map.put("Kiran", "122");
        map.put("Kiran", "122");
        map.put("Kiran", "122");
        map.put("Kiran", "122");

        response.set_return("Kiran");

        return response;

    }

}
```

Please help me , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer , may be useful to somebody .

```
public samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPriceResponse getPrice(
            samples.quickstart.xsd.GetPrice getPrice0) {
getPrice0.getSymbol()) + "")
}
```